# What do exampleRipHi and exampleRipLo represent in this Node.js disassembler library usage code?

Tags: node.js, x86-64, disassembly

```
// iced-x86 features needed: --features "decoder nasm"
const { Decoder, DecoderOptions, Formatter, FormatterSyntax } = require("iced-x86");

/*
This code produces the following output:
00007FFAC46ACDA4 48895C2410           mov       [rsp+10h],rbx
00007FFAC46ACDA9 4889742418           mov       [rsp+18h],rsi
00007FFAC46ACDAE 55                   push      rbp
00007FFAC46ACDAF 57                   push      rdi
00007FFAC46ACDB0 4156                 push      r14
00007FFAC46ACDB2 488DAC2400FFFFFF     lea       rbp,[rsp-100h]
00007FFAC46ACDBA 4881EC00020000       sub       rsp,200h
00007FFAC46ACDC1 488B0518570A00       mov       rax,[rel 7FFA`C475`24E0h]
00007FFAC46ACDC8 4833C4               xor       rax,rsp
00007FFAC46ACDCB 488985F0000000       mov       [rbp+0F0h],rax
00007FFAC46ACDD2 4C8B052F240A00       mov       r8,[rel 7FFA`C474`F208h]
00007FFAC46ACDD9 488D05787C0400       lea       rax,[rel 7FFA`C46F`4A58h]
00007FFAC46ACDE0 33FF                 xor       edi,edi
*/

const exampleBitness = 64;
const exampleRipLo = 0xC46ACDA4;
const exampleRipHi = 0x00007FFA;
const exampleCode = new Uint8Array([
    0x48, 0x89, 0x5C, 0x24, 0x10, 0x48, 0x89, 0x74, 0x24, 0x18, 0x55, 0x57, 0x41, 0x56, 0x48, 0x8D,
    0xAC, 0x24, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x48, 0x81, 0xEC, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x8B, 0x05,
    0x18, 0x57, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x48, 0x33, 0xC4, 0x48, 0x89, 0x85, 0xF0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4C, 0x8B,
    0x05, 0x2F, 0x24, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x05, 0x78, 0x7C, 0x04, 0x00, 0x33, 0xFF
]);
const hexBytesColumnByteLength = 10;

const decoder = new Decoder(exampleBitness, exampleCode, DecoderOptions.None);
// You have to enable the bigint feature to get i64/u64 APIs, not all browsers support BigInt
decoder.ipLo = exampleRipLo;
decoder.ipHi = exampleRipHi;
// This decodes all bytes. There's also `decode()` which decodes the next instruction,
// `decodeInstructions(count)` which decodes `count` instructions and `decodeOut(instruction)`
// which overwrites an existing instruction.
const instructions = decoder.decodeAll();

// Create a nasm formatter. It supports: Masm, Nasm, Gas (AT&T) and Intel (XED).
// There's also `FastFormatter` which uses less code (smaller wasm files).
//     const formatter = new FastFormatter();
const formatter = new Formatter(FormatterSyntax.Nasm);

// Change some options, there are many more
formatter.digitSeparator = "`";
formatter.firstOperandCharIndex = 10;

// Format the instructions
instructions.forEach(instruction => {
    const disasm = formatter.format(instruction);

    // Eg. "00007FFAC46ACDB2 488DAC2400FFFFFF     lea       rbp,[rsp-100h]"
    let line = ("0000000" + instruction.ipHi.toString(16)).substr(-8).toUpperCase() +
               ("0000000" + instruction.ipLo.toString(16)).substr(-8).toUpperCase();
    line += " ";
    const startIndex = instruction.ipLo - exampleRipLo;
    exampleCode.slice(startIndex, startIndex + instruction.length).forEach(b => {
        line += ("0" + b.toString(16)).substr(-2).toUpperCase();
    });
    for (let i = instruction.length; i < hexBytesColumnByteLength; i++)
        line += "  ";
    line += " ";
    line += disasm;

    console.log(line);
});
```

I'm learning Assembly as a prior web developer (hence tinkering with a disassembler Node.js library) and reading the [Intel x86 Architecture Developer Manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html) and somehow I dont recognize the terminology or purpose / implications of the variables used here:

```
const exampleRipLo = 0xC46ACDA4;
const exampleRipHi = 0x00007FFA;
```

What do they represent and how should I decide which values to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIP is the 64-bit program counter on x86-64. The disassembler is using RIP to keep track of the address of each instruction.

`exampleRip` is the start address for `exampleCode`, to be shown as the address of each instruction.

Normally you'd use a single 64-bit integer variable for that, but JavaScript numbers are IEEE `double` floating point so they round large numbers to a multiple of some power of 2, i.e. round away the low bits of big numbers, making it unusable for kernel addresses (in the high half of the canonical address range).  (awk also uses `double`, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649013/why-does-awk-print-0xffffffffbb6002e0-as-ffffffffbb600000-using-printf on unix.SE is an example of the effect, with FP explanation.)

That's the point of this comment:

> // You have to enable the bigint feature to get i64/u64 APIs, not all browsers support BigInt

They're explaining that they're *not* using the BigInt feature, so instead they use two variables (exampleRipHi and exampleRipLo) to implement one 64-bit variable.

```
const exampleRipLo = 0xC46ACDA4;
const exampleRipHi = 0x00007FFA;
```

**That's the JS version of `uint64_t exampleRip = 0x00007FFAC46ACDA4`**

Comment: Thank you. Why is it set to 0x00007FFAC46ACDA4 as opposed to 0 or some other number? What should the specific value represent?

Comment: @J.Todd: Just a choice of example.  Perhaps from a real Linux system where a shared library was loaded; the address looks about right for that.  It's not aligned by 16 so it's not the start of a function compiled with default GCC or clang options, though.